# Server SSL certificate verification failed when setting up ReviewBoard with a SVN repo

Tags: svn, ssl, certificate, review-board

After several hours, I finally got ReviewBoard working on a ubuntu machine. However, when I tried to add a SVN repo to ReviewBoard, I encountered an error:

`Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://192.168.0.110/svn/FHT360' Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted`

I followed some suggestions to manually type the following in the terminal:

```
sudo svn list https://192.168.0.110/svn/FHT360
```

and then type `p` to `permanently accept this certificate anyway` and it is able to list all folders in the repo.

When I turn back to reviewboard and retry, the error wouldn't go way. Is there a way I can tell reviewboard just to **permanently accept this certificate anyway**?

[Update] I didn't find the solution myself. I gave up Reviewboard and went with Phabricator instead and was pleased by the choice.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem come from that you are doing that for your own user and the review board is owned by another user which is www-data

I think your issue is solved here <s>https://code.google.com/p/reviewboard/issues/detail?id=2649</s>

you can follow these steps

```
$ sudo -u www-data -s
$ export HOME=/var/www/reviewboard/data
$ <svn command here>
```

accept the certificate permanently.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of the Python Library you are using? If it is greater than 2.7.9 this is most probably a problem in using the Python library.